# 300 select lists with 2k same items each

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, drop-down-menu

I have 300 select lists with 2k items each. They are all the same. 
Atm I fill it like this

```
var buyers = buyerRepository.Query.Where(x => x.isArchived == false).OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
        var items = buyers.Select(r =>
                new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Value = r.Id.ToString(),
                    Text = r.Name + ", " + r.Address + ", " + (r.PostNumber.HasValue ? r.PostNumber.Value.ToString() : "-") + ", " + r.CityName
                }).AsEnumerable();

        ViewBag.PossibleBuyers = items; (around 1.8k items)
```

and filling is rather fast and that's not problem.

Problem is when I try to show it on page

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count (300 items) ; i++)
     {

         <div class="control-group">

        <div class="span8">
             @Model[i].Buyer
             </div>
         <div>
      @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model[i].BuyerId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.PossibleBuyers, @Html.LocalizeString("String_Choose"), new { @class = "searchable span4", @id = "ddl" })
         </div>
       </div>
      }
```

This page loads a looong time. Is there a way to store or show the dropdown to make it faster?

I hope I'm making some stupid mistake and this can be done much faster. I understand there are ways to do this with ajax but I'm hoping it can be done with simple html. I was hoping it can be sped up because I use same list or my select list.

All droplists are searchable when they load,but loading is close to 10 minutes.

Comment: The two possible issue that would make this slow are either you are downloading a large file and/or the browser is taking a long time to render the dropdowns. Use the developer tools to see where the bottleneck is and start from there.

Comment: Is the resulting web page supposed to be used by a human?

Comment: at first browser shows 10+ lists but later it takes well over a second for each dropdown to show. It's the same dropdown,shouldn't copying text take a lot less then that?

Comment: @Tallmaris
yes, a person has to choose items from list to link with name that gets generated by @Model[i].Buyer

Comment: Instead of using selects, use http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ to make an AJAX call for the values and display that instead of loading 600K values on the browser at once. It's not all the same, it's copies of the same, so it makes the DOM really large, ideally, you would created just one popup div with the options and share that with all the combos

Comment: first rule: don't use select lists with more than 100 values max (no human can work with 2000+ lists...)

Comment: It's searchable so that wasn't problem. I'll try the approach with pop up div